# gcloud can connect but gsutil cannot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Trying to use `gcloud` & `gsutil` from a laptop. `gcloud` can connect but `gsutil` cannot:

```
mylaptop:~ jamiet$ gcloud projects list | head -2
PROJECT_ID           NAME                 PROJECT_NUMBER
dev-99999            dev-99999            999999999999
mylaptop:~ jamiet$ gsutil ls
INFO 0305 21:11:10.561232 util.py] Retrying request, attempt #4...
INFO 0305 21:11:23.826426 util.py] Retrying request, attempt #5...
^CCaught CTRL-C (signal 2) - exiting
```

Any suggestions what I can do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Do you have a current project set in `gcloud`? Without one `gcloud projects` still works (across projects) but `gsutil` might not be happy. Check with `gcloud info | grep '^Project'`

Comment: Do you have a `~/.boto` config file? If so rename it (or move it elsewhere) temporarily and re-try, sometimes config files written by older gsutil versions may cause trouble to newer versions

Comment: Hi @DanCornilescu, yep, I do have a current project set. It is specified if I issue `gcloud config list`.

Comment: I do not have a `~/.boto` config file.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I figured it out, was down to human error. Sorry for the wild goose chase, but thank you for replying.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out to be human error. Internal proxy settings were wrong. Sorry folks, thx to those that replied.

Comment: It would be helpful for others that are receiving the same error if you shared your solution.

Comment: I changed the http_proxy env var

Comment: Not on a laptop, restarting the cloud shell worked for me.

Comment: This post is worthless without details.

Comment: I provided the details in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I use clash as my proxy, and use port 7890 as my proxy port. There was a setting in my .zshrc file:

```
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1
```

After unset them, I can use gsutil to download smoothly

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by deleting `~/.boto` file.