# "gcloud init" is ok , but gsutil can't work in Mac Terminal, continuing " Retrying request"

Tags: gsutil

I want to use gsutil to download cloud storage's bucket file, but it is continuing retrying request. I use the gsutil command in Mac Terminal.

The "gcloud int" has succeeded. Besides, gsutil can work in Cloud Shell.

```
gsutil ls gs://tm_ufs


INFO 0604 14:17:49.749002 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #1...
INFO 0604 14:18:51.684501 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #2...
INFO 0604 14:19:54.875942 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #3...
INFO 0604 14:21:03.459085 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #4...
INFO 0604 14:22:22.220589 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #5...
INFO 0604 14:23:48.716924 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #6...
INFO 0604 14:25:20.733894 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #7...
INFO 0604 14:26:52.750410 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #8...
INFO 0604 14:28:24.763793 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #9...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a previous discussion on the topic:

[gcloud can connect but gsutil cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119629/gcloud-can-connect-but-gsutil-cannot)

Turned out to be proxy issue. I suspect it might be the problem in this case as well.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I have fixed the problem by resolving proxy issue, thanks.